# how to write a method for different Matrix types without explicitly specifying type of Mat in opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, types, typedef

My question might be sitting somewhere in Stackoverflow that I couldn't find, if so, could you give me link.

Basically, I want to write a method that can be used for all matrix types. My method is as follows:

```
Mat my_func(Mat in){
    Mat out(in.rows, in.cols, in.type());
    for(int i =0; i < x; i++)
        for(int j =0; j < x; j++)
            out.at<in.type()>(i,j) = in.at<in.type()>(j,i); //this is just an example,
                                                 //consider that I need to use
                                                 //out.at<in.type()>(i,j) part
}
```

`out.at<in.type()>(i,j)` gives error as it doesn't accept `<in.type>`, it requires `<double>, <float>` etc.

I solved this problem by

```
if(in.type() == 5)
    out.at<float>(i,j) = //do something for float
else if (in.type() == 6)
    out.at<double>(i,j) = //do something for double
```

There should be a better way, but I couldn't find. I searched related to `typedef` but I couldn't understand much from what I have found.

Note that: `in.type() = 5` indicates that Matrix named `in` is a `mat of floats`, similarly `6` is `mat of doubles`.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: `typedef` enables you to define new types of objects. This doesn't seem to be what you're trying to do. The solution you've arrived at appears to be the only one. Maybe there's something different but I'm not enough widely experienced in C++ to tell for sure. But even if there is something different it will most likely follow similar logic. Why is the current solution not good enough for you?

Comment: Do you intend to have different functionality for `double` and `float`..? Or do you need to put them through the same functions..?

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke, it is not good because I dont want to write `if (double), else if (float)` every methods. I think `typedef` is what I need but I don't know how to use for my need if you know some link that can help me, it'd be really nice

Comment: @scap3y, I want same functionality for both `double` and `float` and may be other types as well. I just don't want to specifically indicate   `if (type == 1), else if(type == 2), else if (...)` and so on. I just need a *global word/usage* for all of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`m.at<type>(i,j)` is a template expression. the compiler has to resolve the type at compile time.

so, any try to cheat at runtime like `m1.at<m2.type()>(i,j)` is doomed.

the good news is , that there are template Mat's as well, like `Mat_<float>` which you can access just like `m(i,j)`  ( without the pesky template brackets ).

so, your example code might even look like:

```
template<class T>
Mat_<T> my_func(Mat_<T> in){
    Mat_<T> out(in.cols, in.rows);
    for(int i =0; i < in.cols; i++)
        for(int j =0; j < in.rows; j++)
            out(j,i) = in(i,j); 
    return out;
}

int main()
{
// called like :
Mat_<int> in;
Mat_<int> res = my_func(in);
return 0;
}
```

honestly, it's a very rare case, that you don't know your Mat's type at compile time, for those you'll still need code like if type==5 do_something, arrays of function pointers indexed by typeid or similar.

Comment: I was just about suggest a template class.. +1, @berak.. Anyway, in case this doesn't work, try to [convert](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=convertto#void%20Mat%3a%3aconvertTo%28OutputArray%20m,%20int%20rtype,%20double%20alpha,%20double%20beta%29%20const) your `cv::Mat` to a type that you always know (even if you don't know the type during compile/run time)..

Comment: Thanks for answer, I saw `template <class T> before` but didn't understand that time. One simple question: is this method as fast as the code I wrote, or is it slightly slower? Consider I'm going to call this function for millions of times.

Comment: it's definitely *not* slower. all the confusing template stuff is done at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Better ways that come to mind:

1. Use `Mat_<...>` instead of `Mat`.
2. Instead of `at` and assignment, extract a 1×1 rectangle an use `Mat::copyTo()`.
3. Encapsulate assignment to a function of your own, do the `case (Mat.type()) {...}` routine inside that function.

Comment: Is `copyTo()` method as fast as `.at`? For an Mat whose size is 1Kx1K, I will have to call 1M times. I will run this method thousands of times, I will have to call `copyTo()` billons of times.

Comment: No, it's not fast (you can measure yourself). If your goal is to build a symmetric matrix fast, try transposing a matrix abd adding it to the original one

Comment: I was thinking it is not that fast, but you are right I could have tested it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function to write any type of mat to txtfile which can be read in matlab using matlab function 'dlmread'

```
int main()
{ 
  Mat matDilate;
  SaveToNotepad(matDilate,"C://matDilate.txt");
  return 0;
}


template <class T>
void CFindObjectByThreshColorImage::PrintMat(T* image, int rows, int cols, std::string fileName)
{
try
{
    ofstream fout(fileName); 
    if(fout.is_open())
    {
        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < rows; i ++)
        {
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < cols; j ++)
            {
                fout << image[i*cols+j]<<"\t"; // behaves like cout - cout is also a stream
                //cerr<< image[i*cols+j]<<"\t";
            }
            fout << endl;

        }
        fout.close();
    }
}
catch (exception& e)
{
    LOG( ALG_LOGGER, Error, "CFindHoughCircle::file write Exception " + string(e.what()));
}
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
>// SaveToNotepad 
>//writes the mat to the destination  fileName
>// Example :SaveToNotepad(diff_im,"C://diff_im.txt");
>//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void CFindObjectByThreshColorImage::SaveToNotepad( Mat WriteMatrix, std::string fileName)
{        
int iImgType = WriteMatrix.type();// finding which datat type it is 

switch (iImgType)
{
case 0:
    // "CV_8U";
    PrintMat((uchar*) WriteMatrix.data, WriteMatrix.rows , WriteMatrix.cols, fileName);// 
    break;
case 1:
    // "CV_8S";
    PrintMat(( char*) WriteMatrix.data, WriteMatrix.rows , WriteMatrix.cols, fileName);
    break;
case 2:
    //"CV_16U";
    PrintMat(( ushort*) WriteMatrix.data, WriteMatrix.rows , WriteMatrix.cols, fileName);
    break;
case 3:
    // "CV_16S";
    PrintMat(( short*) WriteMatrix.data, WriteMatrix.rows , WriteMatrix.cols, fileName);
    break;
case 4:
    // "CV_32S";
    PrintMat(( int*) WriteMatrix.data, WriteMatrix.rows , WriteMatrix.cols, fileName);
    break;
case 5:
    // "CV_32F";
    PrintMat(( float*) WriteMatrix.data, WriteMatrix.rows , WriteMatrix.cols, fileName);
    break;
case 6:
    // "CV_64F";
    PrintMat(( double*) WriteMatrix.data, WriteMatrix.rows , WriteMatrix.cols, fileName);
    break;
default:
    LOG( ALG_LOGGER, Error, "CFindHoughCircle:: Mat type Exception " + fileName);
    break;
}
```